# Powersell get-date on same line as get-service

Tags: powershell

Looking for help, I am trying to get this list to populate the current time when running this PS script.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content E:\Scripts\3PL-pkgs\Tools\ServiceChecker\machines_List.txt


$servicecheck = ForEach ($server in $serverlist) 
{
$serverlist = Get-Content E:\Scripts\3PL-pkgs\Tools\ServiceChecker\machines_List.txt
$time = Get-Date -Format g
Get-Service -Computername $server "foo*", "bar*", "biz*", "baz*", "Exp*"  | time, machinename, name, status
 }


$servicecheck
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you just want the output to include a column for time? Look at calculated properties. Also this code should be throwing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Calculated Property can solve this need for you.  A Calculated property allows you to add a hashtable to a list of objects in a `Select-Object` statement to reference existing properties which aren't exposed in that current pipeline. 
 They look like this:

```
@{Name='ColumnName';Expression={#SomeCodeHere}}
```

So, since you already have a variable with the value you want stored within `$time`, all we have to do is add this to the list of columns you're selecting like so

```
Get-Service -Computername $server "f*"   |
   Select-Object @{L='time';exp={$time}}, machinename, name, status
}
```

For the following results:

```
time              MachineName Name         Status
----              ----------- ----         ------
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   Fax         Stopped
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   fdPHost     Stopped
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   FDResPub    Stopped
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   fhsvc       Stopped
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   FontCache   Running
3/7/2018 11:14 AM localhost   FrameServer Stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an alias property to your object like this -

```
Get-Service -Computername $server "foo*", "bar*", "biz*", "baz*", "Exp*"  |
foreach {
$_ | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Time -Value $time -PassThru
} |
Select time, machinename, name, status
```

Using the [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/), you can overcome the situation.